# Is there a test data builder that works with classes without default constructor?

Tags: c#, test-data, nbuilder, bogus

Due to introducing C# 8's non-nullable reference types to my codebase, I'm changing my domain classes to have constructors that accept parameters to initialize values of their non-nullable properties.

In unit tests I don't want to bother with filling these constructor parameters with meaningless data, so I tried using libraries like NBuilder and Bogus to create instances for me. Bogus example is `var myObject = Faker.Generate<MyClass>();`.

**However, looks like both Bogus and NBuilder expect my classes to have parameterless constructors or to write some configuration code for my class**. They can't just discover my constructor and call it with generated parameter values. When asked Bogus creator, I was responded that they don't handle this situation on purpose because of possible ambiguity when there is more than one constructor. But I don't mind if a framework uses some default behaviour for picking a constructor (e.g. take the one which has the most parameters).

**So, is there a library that would discover and use constructors when generating objects**?

Answer (score 2):

[AutoBogus](https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus) does exactly what is needed:
`var myObject = AutoFaker.Generate<MyClass>();`